# Wordpress Header shortcut not showing

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a template in wordpress from HTML. Now my problem is when I login and go to pages I don't see shortcuts at the top. Like **Edit page** etc just plain white background.

Here is a screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/48kgO.jpg

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Check your `error_log`. Validate your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have wp_head() and wp_footer() calls in your template files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Hope this helps.